# Start columns at end of container with Bulma.io

Tags: css, bulma

I would like to know if there is a good way to start the columns of [Bulma.io](https://bulma.io/) at the end of its container. The usual setup is:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="columns">
    <div class="column">
      First
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      Second
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      Third
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

which spreads the columns evenly throughout the container.

```
-----------------------------------------------------
|               | |                | |              |
|               | |                | |              |
-----------------------------------------------------
```

I know it is possible to make them shorter and left-aligned with `is-(size)` classes. I would like to to the same but make the right-aligned so the following happens:

```
-----------------------------------------------------
|                      | |       | |       | |      |
|                      | |       | |       | |      |
-----------------------------------------------------
```

I have looked up the documentation but I couldn't find any built in way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid there's no built in way for `.columns`. For some reason `.is-right` class is only available for `.tags`, `.buttons` and some more. What you could do is to create and use your own utility/helper class:

```
.columns.is-right {
  justify-content: flex-end;
}
```

Comment: You are right, I have found an issue with a similar request and the response from the creator is to be read here: https://github.com/jgthms/bulma/issues/566
Your answer is correct btw, thanks!

Comment: What about mobile? Do you just disable that on mobile? What if you want to keep it on mobile, you just create bunch of classes? They should implement this feature.